# Report builder 3.0 styles in table wizard

Tags: sql-server-2008, report, builder, reportbuilder

When using the *Insert Table Wizard* in Report Builder 3, one of the steps is to select a style, e.g. Corporate, Forest, Generic.

Is there a way that I can create my own style and include it so that it is visible in this list?

Comment: I did some research and I'm afraid to say that there is no way of putting more styles in the Table wizard

Comment: The closest I've seen to this is doing it in BIDS and Visual Studio http://web.archive.org/web/20120811123551/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/yanivy/archive/2010/08/03/create-custom-templates-and-styles-for-ssrs-2008.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No unfortuantely there is no way to input your own design to the list. What i recommend you do instead, is create an empty report using the report builder (table/columns) and use that as a template. Then you can just utilize that and save it with a different name.